# When donating something liluy nishmas someone, is there any reason to write the name of the person you're donating for in/on the item?

Tags: sources-mekorot, zechut-merit

I see a lot of people do write it on plaques or in seforim, but what would the reason be?

(I have heard that maybe it's for people to see it and do something as a zchus for them, but practically, I don't think people read the plaques/inscriptions.)